# Deleting a node based on child value in Pugixml

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, pugixml

What I have so far can delete all the children of the actual node I want to delete but not the node itself.

```
pugi::xml_document doc;
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file("config/config.xml");
pugi::xpath_query query_network_last_run("//state[network/network_last_run='2']");
pugi::xpath_node_set network_last_run = query_network_last_run.evaluate_node_set(doc);
```

The part below removes specific parts -- but  I want to delete the **network** based on a child value (network_last_run), not this child of it.

```
network_last_run[0].node().remove_child("network_gateway");
```

XML file structure

```
<root>
 <state>
  <network>
   <network_last_run>2<network_last_run>
   <network_gateway>192.168.3.1</network_gateway>
  </network>
 </state>
</root>
```

I tried to step back up using

```
network_last_run[0].node().parent().remove_child("network");
```

But it seems that only modifies the actual structure stored in memory, (removes the first one) and not the structure the query has.

I could probably do this in a for loop and use an if condition to check whether the child node value matches, but I would like to do it through a query if possible?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it a bit, this is the solution I made (and I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere else so I figured I could just post it here)

Essentially it changes the name of the actual node in question. After that, it runs a query (the node set of which could be used in a for loop) and removes any child elements with the new name.

```
network_last_run[0].node().set_name("removal");



pugi::xpath_query query_removals("//state");
pugi::xpath_node_set removals = query_removals.evaluate_node_set(doc);

removals[0].node().remove_child("removal");
```